# Replacing stock dnsmasq with optware dnsmasq

Tags: linux, process, router, dnsmasq

This question if for DD-WRT installed on e3000 with optware.

I have replaced the stock dnsmasq to get logging, using this: http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=660694
I installed optware on my 16gb usb and installed dnsmasq.

Runs fine when service started, but have two problems:

- "ps aux | grep dnsmasq" shows two processes

---

```
 nobody   29791  0.0  0.8   1284   520 ?        S    12:03   0:01 /opt/sbin/dnsmasq
 root     29792  0.0  0.4   1268   256 ?        S    12:03   0:00 /opt/sbin/dnsmasq
```

- On device reboot, the dnsmasq service does not load up. I have to manually load it using "service dnsmasq start" and loads up to processes like the ps grep above.

Comment: A note: this mentions DD-WRT, but could easily relate to endpoints in a company network, especially were logging features are concerned. Please consider this before marking off-topic.

Comment: That said, even if it can fit here you might still find more people who are well-versed in the software to answer your question over at http://superuser.com.

Comment: Yeah, I will move my question to superuser. I just wanted to add answer to my first problem: "There are always 2 processes running for each dhcp network. The subprocess is because dnsmasq setuids to nobocy to run the external script specified in --dhcp-script. This is expected behavior." src: https://answers.launchpad.net/nova/+question/181398

Comment: Note this question has been [cross-posted at SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/461705/replacing-stock-dnsmasq-with-optware-dnsmasq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answers to my problems. May be useful to someone else:

1. "There are always 2 processes running for each dhcp network. The subprocess is because dnsmasq setuids to nobody to run the external script specified in --dhcp-script. This is expected behavior." src: answers.launchpad.net/nova/+question/181398
2. As one of the processes was nobody; during boot up, user 'nobody' was not initialized. Added these two lines to /opt/etc/init.d/S56dnsmasq:

> grep -q nobody /etc/group || echo "nobody:x:99:" >> /etc/group
>
> grep -q nobody     /etc/passwd || echo "nobody:x:99:99:nobody:/var:/bin/false" >> /etc/passwd

Works like a charm!

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Thanks for leaving the answer for your own problem to help others. You can go ahead and mark this answer as your accepted answer.